# Easy way to inject js in tinymce iframe?

Tags: tinymce, iframe

I was wondering if there is any direct hook to inject some javascript into tinymce iframe?

Comment: does tinymce have an iframe? can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes it has. Whole editor area is an iframe.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This question is **javascript/TinyMCE** related, not **WordPress** specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress injects its own external script files in the TinyMCE editor `iframe`, see for example the `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpembed/plugin.js` file:

```
(function ( tinymce ) {
    'use strict';

    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wpembed', function ( editor, url ) {
        editor.on( 'init', function () {
            var scriptId = editor.dom.uniqueId();

            var scriptElm = editor.dom.create( 'script', {
                id: scriptId,
                type: 'text/javascript',
                src: url + '/../../../wp-embed.js'
            } );

            editor.getDoc().getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].appendChild( scriptElm );
        } );
    } );
})( window.tinymce );
```

The `plugin.js` file is loaded in TinyMCE using the `tiny_mce_plugins` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, Tinymce uses this [javascript to create iframe](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/editor_template_src.js), so you've to edit the javascript to load additional javascript file into iframe.

Thats why there will not be any hook to inject javascript into iframe.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a solution.